# Unable to read data from the Cloud Firestore in my flutter application

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried integrating my flutter app with Cloud Firestore. On a page, in the app, I just want to read data from the cloud firestore and print it on that page. I am new and don't know much about making backends, so I have tried a couple of tutorials from youtube and also read some articles on StackOverflow but I am still not able to read data from the cloud firestore. So I think that I have made a mistake somewhere. So here are all the snippets and the changes I have made to my app.

This is how my Firestore data looks like :

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPZtx.png
```

This is a page on which I want to print data from the firestore cloud.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  Future getPosts() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("events").get();

    return qn.docs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPosts(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Loading...',
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    snapshot.data[index].data['name'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

These are the dependencies of my application,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher:
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
```

I was also getting an error due to null safety. So I decided to disable the null safety by changing the environment in my pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

While writing the code for the page, I took help from this youtube tutorial:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uBjMFoyT-I

Been working all day trying to get this work done, So any help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder is not in state of being active, but he is done

Update your condition

```
 else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.data != null) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    snapshot.data![index].data['name'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```

Comment: After updating the condition, and opening the app on my emulator I receive a red screen with an error that goes :

 "NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. \n
Receiver: null \n
Tried calling: [](0)"

Comment: Sorry @samit. Updated my answer. You probably missing some data, you need to check if you have data and update your listview to real length

Comment: I did as you said, the code works but I see a blank screen on the emulator, but I want the data from Firestore. Is my cloud firebase wrong?

Comment: What is your firestore structure? Is your path in call right? I would verify this

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code in the `Text` widget to something like this:

```
Text(
           snapshot.data[index].data()['name'],
        ),
```

When accessing the data from a DocumentSnapshot, you must access by using the method `.data()` Don't forget to include the parentheses.

Comment: But why do I not see the data from the firebase?
I see a blank container when I run the app.

Comment: try printing snapshot.data[index].data() and tell me what it returns